# extract info from dataset - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a financial data for a few years which has:
**'Month-year' , sales amount** ex:
['jan-2020' , 984655],
['feb-2020', -21632],
and so on....

- for profit and - when loss is made.
  I want to calculate the following:

- numbers of months in the data
- amount of loss/profit  over the entire period
- most profitable month (date and amount)
- worst month in terms of losses (date and amount)
  average change (total/number of months)

I tried the following at least to get numbers of months but was unsuccesful
`

```
function getMonthDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    return(
        endDate.getMonth() -
        startDate.getMonth() +
    );
}
console.log(getMonthDifference)
```

Comment: `console.log(getMonthDifference)` - you are not even _calling_ the function here. `startDate.getMonth() +` - plus _what_? This currently is just a syntax error at this point. If these issues are an indication of your current level of JS knowledge, then you should be reading up on some basics at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with regular js functions. Read inline comments, check result by pressing blue button "Run code snippet":

```js
// Data
const data = [
  ['jan-2020', 984655],
  ['feb-2020', -21632],
  ['mar-2020', 621632],
  ['apr-2020', 283726],
  ['may-2020', 10039],
  ['jun-2020', -40044],
  ['jul-2020', -10032],
  ['aug-2020', 50038],
  ['sep-2020', 915633],
  ['oct-2020', 494372],
  ['nov-2020', 374757],
  ['dec-2020', -51611]
];

// Get number of months in data
console.log("Total months in data:", data.length);
console.log("---------");

// Amount of losses over entire period
const lossMonths = data.filter(el => el[1] < 0);
console.log("All loss months:");
for(const mo of lossMonths) console.log(`${mo[0]}: ${mo[1]}`);
console.log("Sum of losses:", lossMonths.map(el => el[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log("---------");

// Amount of profit over entire period
const profitMonths = data.filter(el => el[1] > 0);
console.log("All profit months:");
for(const mo of profitMonths) console.log(`${mo[0]}: ${mo[1]}`);
console.log("Sum of profit:", profitMonths.map(el => el[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log("---------");

// Most worst month (date and amount)
const lossMonthSorted = lossMonths.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1]);
console.log("Most worst month:", lossMonthSorted[0].join(": "));
console.log("---------");

// Most profitable month (date and amount)
const profitMonthsSorted = profitMonths.sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1]);
console.log("Most profitable month:", profitMonthsSorted[0].join(": "));
console.log("---------");

// Total and average
const total = data.map(el => el[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
const average = total / data.length;
console.log("Total:", total);
console.log("Average per month:", average.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works, will only need the average

Comment: Didn't notice text about average... What exactly do you want to see in `average change`?

Comment: average in changes in profit/loss over the entire period, I think I will need the total divided by the number of months.

Comment: Ok, updated the answer at it's very end. If all good, pls accept the answer)

Comment: I did manually add the sum and I am getting different figure than sum I am getting on the code.